# Implement AEM search using query builder API using wildcard-contains in node name

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr, aem-6, jcr-sql2

I have a requirement to fetch search results based on partial/wild card in node name to retrieve AEM forms portal data.

For example, if there are multiple draft Id node under any user-email (Unique node created under /conten/forms/fp). each draft application node will reside under conten/forms/fp/*.com|.net*/metadata/draftId

Note: User nodes will have .com or .net in the end. Image also attached for reference. I should get testsonar@mailiantor.com/testsonar%40@mailinator.com as result since the user has more than one draft application.

[image]

My requirement is to find out users who are having multiple drafts. Can anyone suggest this would be possible using Query builder API . I have tried below predicate but noticed that wild card is not supporting in path.

```
type=nt:unstructured
path=/content/forms/fp/*/drafts/metadata
path.exact=false
path.false=false
```

Comment: Could post what you have tried till now? If you wnat to learn about query builder api then below link can be useful https://hashimkhan.in/aem-adobecq5-code-templates/query-builder/

Comment: I have tried below predicates but wild card is not supporting in path.  type=nt:unstructured
path=/content/forms/fp/*/drafts/metadata
path.exact=false
path.false=false

Comment: Try using the like operation on molecule name property.

Answer (score 0):

When using predicates you should be able to use something like this:

```
group.1_property.value=%term%
group.1_property=jcr:path
group.1_property.operation=like
```